# Automapper unable to map foreign key properties in unit test project

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have declared a map that maps an entity to a DTO. That DTO has a foreign key reference to another DTO that has to be mapped by automapper, using ProjectTo. This works perfectly fine when running the solution, but when i use the maps in my unit tests, in doesnt work until i remove the foreign key property from my DTO. I think there is something missing in my AutoMapper setup, but im not sure.

The model looks like this:

```
public class PendingReportDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid PatientId { get; set; }
    public long Identifier { get; set; }
    public DatabaseType Database { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReportedDate { get; set; }
    public PatientDto Patient { get; set; }
    public IdentifierType IdentifierType { get; set; }
}
```

The map looks like this:

```
CreateMap<Report, PendingReportDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Database, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Database))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.PatientId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.PatientId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ReportedDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ReportedDate))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Identifier, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Identifier))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.IdentifierType, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.IdentifierType))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Patient, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Patient));
```

Patient has it's own map that works perfectly fine on it's own.
Above map is used like this:

```
return ReadContext.Reports
            .Where(x => x.Database == databaseType && x.ReportedDate == null)
            .ProjectTo<PendingReportDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

When doing that i get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'bindings')
```

Automapper is setup like this in unit test project:

```
public static class SetupAutomapper
{
    public static IMapper Setup()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(opts =>
        {
            var profiles = typeof(MappingProfile).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(x => typeof(MappingProfile).IsAssignableFrom(x));
            foreach (var profile in profiles.Distinct())
            {
                opts.AddProfile(Activator.CreateInstance(profile) as MappingProfile);
            }
        });

        return config.CreateMapper();
    }
}
```

It works if i use a select statement, instead of using ProjectTo to map to my DTO.

UPDATE:

Further investigation shows that the culprit might be me running an in-memory database, instead of my regular database, when running my unit tests. If i swap it out, even with the same dataset, it works as intended. Could this be a bug with EF Core in-memory db and automapper?

Comment: Further investigation shows that the culprit might be me running an in-memory database, instead of my regular database, when running my unit tests. If i swap it out, even with the same dataset, it works as intended. Could this be a bug with EF Core in-memory db and automapper?

Comment: Also, the profiles seems to work, as i stated in my comment above. If i change the DB from an in-memory db to a regular database, then it works just fine. Also, everything works, except mapping via reverse navigation properties, when im using the memory DB.

Comment: I see that you linked to assembly scanning for adding configurations, but surely that is not the only way to do it, since the AutoMapper API has a way to add one profile at a time. In another project i simply add a type instead, it can be done in several different ways

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I tried adding the profiles via. assembly scanning, but it made no difference. I think it could be something with Automapper in conjunction with In-memory ef core

Comment: What the provider does has little to do with AM. If it works with a real db, you just need to make your test infrastructure closer to the real thing. I'm sure a lot of people already did that.

Comment: I agree, since Automapper does not create SQL at all, but IQueryable<T>. But, there is still something fishy when combining automapper with the in-memory EF core database, and using .ProjectTo. When doing normal selects, it works just fine. It might be something configurable, that is why im seeking help on SO. There's no need to downvote my question or answer consdescendingly, just because i disagree with you. That's not very constructive.

Comment: The only thing different about my test setup is my database. It's still Entity Framework Core, just an in-memory database instead of a real database. I cannot see how i can get closer to my real infrastructure without running my tests on a normal db. But if i do that, it works, i tested it earlier :) Im just not interested in doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So im pretty sure I found the issue with using ProjectTo to map reverse navigation properties. The issue doesn't lie with Automapper itself or the way I have configurated it in my test setup.

The culprit seems to be the db provider: Entity Framework Core in-memory db.

If i swap out the database with a localdb or a regular MS SQL DB, it works just fine. The in-memory db provider has certain limitations, which seems to limit the usage of ProjectTo with Automapper.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/

How to setup local db:

```
private static void SetupLocalDb(DbContextOptionsBuilder builder)
{
    builder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Testing;Trusted_Connection=True;");
}
```